# How to correctly retrieve the state of a check button in tkinter python?

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm wanting for the user to be able to select and deselect options using checkboxes, and then having the `totalPrice` variable reflect this with a total cost worked out using webscraping functions.

```
pricing_program = tk.Tk()
    pricing_program.title("Pricing calculations")
    width = pricing_program.winfo_screenwidth()
    height = pricing_program.winfo_screenheight()
    pricing_program.geometry("%dx%d" % (width, height))

    def inputData():
        xValue = int(dimensionxInput.get())
        yValue = int(dimensionyInput.get())
        height = int(dimensionHeightEntry.get())

        if xValue == "" or yValue == "" or height == "":
            placeholder.config(text="The input fields cannot be empty")
        elif xValue == "0" or yValue == "0" or height == "0":
            placeholder.config(text="The input fields cannot be 0")
        else:
            totalPrice = 0
            if brickButtonVar == 1:
                brickPrice = brickCalculations(xValue, yValue, height)
                totalPrice += brickPrice
                print(brickPrice)

            if tileButtonVar == 1:
                tilePrice = tileCalculations(xValue, yValue)
                totalPrice += tilePrice

            if concreteButtonVar == 1:
                concretePrice = concreteCalculations(xValue, yValue)
                totalPrice += concretePrice

            if woodFlooringButtonVar == 1:
                flooringPrice = flooringCalculations(xValue, yValue)
                totalPrice += flooringPrice
            totalPrice = str(totalPrice)
            placeholder.config(text=totalPrice)

    topbar = tk.Menu(pricing_program)
    pricing_program.config(menu=topbar)
    topbar.add_command(label="Home", command=mainProgram)
    topbar.add_command(label="Finances", command=financesProgram)
    topbar.add_command(label="Pricing Estimates", command=pricingProgram)
    topbar.add_command(label="Configure Pricing", command=configureProgram)

    about = tk.Label(pricing_program,
                     text="This section of the program works by you inputting the various materials you are requiring, and then uses web scraping to then get a price."
                          " \n In order to use this program, you must enter a value in the dimensions boxes below and then select the materials you are requiring."
                          "\n All inputs should be done as mms.")
    about.config(font=('Helvetica bold', 15))
    about.pack(padx=21)

    dimensionxLabel = tk.Label(pricing_program, text="Input x dimensions:")
    dimensionxLabel.config(font=('Helvetica bold', 10))
    dimensionxLabel.pack()

    dimensionxInput = tk.Entry(pricing_program)
    dimensionxInput.pack()

    dimensionyLabel = tk.Label(pricing_program, text="Input y dimensions:")
    dimensionyLabel.config(font=('Helvetica bold', 10))
    dimensionyLabel.pack()

    dimensionyInput = tk.Entry(pricing_program)
    dimensionyInput.pack()

    dimensionHeightLabel = tk.Label(pricing_program, text="Input height dimensions:")
    dimensionHeightLabel.config(font=('Helvetica bold', 10))
    dimensionHeightLabel.pack()

    dimensionHeightEntry = tk.Entry(pricing_program)
    dimensionHeightEntry.pack()

    brickButtonVar = tk.IntVar()
    tileButtonVar = tk.IntVar()
    concreteButtonVar = tk.IntVar()
    woodFlooringButtonVar = tk.IntVar()

    brickButton = tk.Checkbutton(pricing_program,
                                 text="Bricks",
                                 variable=brickButtonVar,
                                 onvalue=1,
                                 offvalue=0)
    brickButton.pack()

    tileButton = tk.Checkbutton(pricing_program,
                                text="Roof tiles",
                                variable=tileButtonVar,
                                onvalue=1,
                                offvalue=0)
    tileButton.pack()

    concreteButton = tk.Checkbutton(pricing_program,
                                    text="Concrete / foundations",
                                    variable=concreteButtonVar,
                                    onvalue=1,
                                    offvalue=0)
    concreteButton.pack()

    woodFlooringButton = tk.Checkbutton(pricing_program,
                                        text="Wooden Flooring",
                                        variable=woodFlooringButtonVar,
                                        onvalue=1,
                                        offvalue=0)
    woodFlooringButton.pack()

    inputDetailsBtn = tk.Button(pricing_program, text="Input data",
                                command=inputData)
    inputDetailsBtn.pack()

    placeholder = tk.Label(pricing_program, text="")
    placeholder.pack()

    pricing_program.mainloop()
```

My `brickCalculations` function is working and correctly retriving a price if i was to run the function on its own which i did before, but now when i add it as an option with my checkbuttons it doesn't run.

You can see that there is the line `print(brickPrice)` to check if it was the addition that was the issue but it's failing to call the function at all as if the button was not checked. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Tkinter Var objects are *holders* of values, NOT the values themselves.  `brickButtonVar` (for example) can never be equal to 1 - but `brickButtonVar.get()` might be.